# Pyspark explode sql function

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have this schema:

```
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _published-at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- p: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

link_structure = StructType([
    StructField("_VALUE", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_href", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_type", StringType(), True)
    ])

articles_schema = StructType([
    StructField("_id", LongType(), True),
    StructField("_published-at", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_title", StringType(), True),
    StructField("a", ArrayType(link_structure), True),
    StructField("p", ArrayType(StringType()), True)])
```

Sample data:

```
+---+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|_id|_published-at|              _title|                   a|                   p|
+---+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 17|   2004-07-29|SAN FRANCISCO / H...|[[Gwendolyn Tucke...|[Chief juvenile p...|
| 19|   2017-10-05|Nancy Pelosi Lies...|[[so he asked her...|[CNN recently hos...|
| 23|   2017-04-20|University leader...|[[letter, http://...|[Pro-life student...|
| 24|   2011-01-14|What Wine Prices ...|[[A new working p...|[More on:, <a>Fos...|
+---+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

and code for creating an a new column as an array of links from each article:

```
articles_df = articles_df.\
    withColumn("content", fun.col('p')).\
    withColumn("links", fun.array(fun.col('a._href')))
```

data:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|_id|             content|               links|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| 17|[Chief juvenile p...|[[/search/?action...|
| 19|[CNN recently hos...|[[https://www.you...|
| 23|[Pro-life student...|[[http://yourstud...|
| 24|[More on:, <a>Fos...|[[http://www.imf....|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I need to save the links of each article -**each in a separate row**-, so I tried usin the pyspark.sql explode function:

```
df2 = articles_df.select("_id", fun.explode(fun.col('links')))
```

But I'm getting this result:

```
+---+----+
|_id| col|
+---+----+
| 17|null|
| 19|null|
| 23|null|
| 24|null|
+---+----+
```

How it can be done?

Comment: How does the values in links look like?

Comment: updated with links data

Comment: I don't think you'll need to create an array there. Your `a._href` looks like an array itself. A simple `explode('a._href')` should work then.

Comment: It was that way first (without array) but I got empty set, with array I started getting the ids values but with nulls in link column! Is there a need to create a map that contains the id per link instead of array?

Comment: No. The `array` part just zips two columns to create pairs of values. I think it's because the values aren't quoted inside the `a._href` column array.

Comment: I see that the _href is string in the schema. So the whole value is a string and not array. Right? It should have been array but is string?

Comment: The _href is string, but I'm creating an array of strings... so it should be ok I guess. I added the code of schema as well to my post.

Comment: Then why does it show a nested array in links column? I guess, your code reads the array data as string and hence no quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204987/discussion-between-zbeedatm-and-samkart).